# How can I format a bootstrap table to align all contents to the left and only use necessary space?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

```
[ header  ] [ header 2 ] [ header 3      ]
----------------------------------------------------------------------100%
 cell here   and longer   and even longer
----------------------------------------------------------------------100%
 another     row          here
----------------------------------------------------------------------100%
```

In my example above, I want a table that has a width of `100%`, so that the striped table rows (i.e. `<table class="table table-striped">` stretch the full width, but I need all of the content to be left justified and only take up the space needed. I've tried various combinations of:

```
table.something thead th { width: auto !important }
table.something thead th { white-space: nowrap; width; 1%; }
table.something tbody td { white-space: nowrap; width: 1%; }
```

This is for a design spec that I must follow, otherwise I'd just stick with the normal bootstrap table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to set the `table-layout` to `auto` so that the widths of the table and its cells are adjusted to fit the content. And then you set the last column's width to 100%. That will push the other columns to shrink. Lastly to avoid the content in other columns to wrap, you can set `white-space` to `nowrap`.

#### HTML

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>[header]</th>
            <th>[header 2]</th>
            <th>[header 3]</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>cell here</td>
            <td>longer cell here</td>
            <td>longer longer and even longer cell here</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>cell</td>
            <td>longer cell</td>
            <td>longer longer and even longer cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>cell here here</td>
            <td>longer cell here here</td>
            <td>longer longer and even longer cell here here</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

#### CSS

```css
.table {
    table-layout: auto;
}

.table td, .table th {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.table thead th:last-child {
    width: 100%;
}
```

#### Screenshot

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/bd7g1mxp/20/

Comment: `And then you set the last column's width to 100%` That was the ticket! Thank you